# Ubuntu 12.04 dual displays not working

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, video, multiple-monitors

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04. I am having trouble setting up my nVidia settings. I have a monitor connected to the DVI port and a Sony TV connected to the HDMI. I am trying to set up the displays with the TV to the "right of" the monitor. This worked fine in Xubuntu 11.10. Now when I setup using separate X screens, write the Xorg.conf and reboot, my monitor works fine and TV has a gray screen with an X mouse cursor. Basically looks like the window manager has failed. If I setup using twinview it appears to work. However, Ubuntu's display settings only show my one very wide display (3520 x 1080) and calls it "laptop". When I try to run XBMC in full screen mode, it is stretched across both displays. This is driving me crazy!   Please help!

Comment: Are you using Unity (compiz) or Unity2D (metacity)? I'm having the same issue on compiz. `nvidia-settings` however gets it right. My displays have differing resolutions, it seems the same is the case for you?

Answer (score 1):

With separate X displays you could try launching xbmc with the DISPLAY=:1 environment variable, e.g.:

brad0383@yourcomputer:$ DISPLAY=:1 xbmc --fullscreen

Please note the I don't use XBMC so the flag for fullscreen might be different but should be easily discovered in the man page.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but the problem is that the windows manager crashes on the TV display.  I have just a gray screen with an X mouse icon when using separate X displays.  The strange thing is that Xubuntu 12.04 works fine with the same nvidia driver.